# Redirect : resolve vs onEnter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect the user if some conditions aren't right. (typically when he's not connected).

I have 2 solutions to redirect the user found on stackoverflow or ui-router wiki. But i don't understand when they act and what is the best for my use case.

```
{
    name: 'example',
    url: "/example/:idExample",
    templateUrl: '[...]',
    controller: '[...]',
    controllerAs: '[...]',
    onEnter: ['connectedUser', function (connectedUser) {
        console.log("On Enter");
        if (condition) {
            //redirect;
        }
    }],
    resolve: {
        canAccess: function canAccess(connectedUser) {
            console.log("CanAccess");
            if (condition) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    //redirect
                }, 0);
                return $q.reject()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

both of them work great but the $timeout look not pretty to me. however, resolve seem to be called before onEnter and Maybe is better to prevent some useless load?
I am not sur to understand right when use one or the other.

Comment: Resolve can be used to first do some actions to see if the user **can** enter the state. OnEnter is usually used when the user already is in the state, and then do some stuff. So for your usecase I would use `resolve`

Comment: It depends on what the redirect is. Is it really necessary? Usually you may want to just resolve/reject a promise in resolver. And do a redirect for rejected promise in state error handler.